# SQLAlchemy: Passing a Parameter to Object

Tags: python, dependency-injection, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy in my project.

I have two classes, call them Bar and Foo

```
class Bar(object):
    def valueize(self, name):
         # do some crazy magic
         return value


class Foo(Base):
   id = Column(...
   name = Column(...

   @property
   def value(self):
       return self._bar.valueize(self.name)
```

Foo is constructed either by me constructing the object directly or by SQLalchemy when it loads Foo objects from the database. But Foo needs a Bar object in order to work. But how do I get the reference to Bar into the Foo?

Normally, I'd just pass the Bar into the Foo constructor. However, that won't work here because SQLAlchemy is creating the object.

What I want to be able to do is somehow configure a Session with a Bar object such that that bar object is injected into the Foo objects when they are added to the session.

**What I've Tried**

SQLAlchemy has an events system. One of the session events is on_attach. This is called whenever an object is added to the session. However, it is not called when an object is loaded from the database.

There are events which are called when loaded from the database, but they are on a per-mapper basis. The Bar object needs to be associated with an individual session.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one `Bar` for all `Foo`s, you can use a class property or method in `Foo`. Since you haven't taken this obvious path, you seem to need to construct a new `Bar` for every new `Foo`. Probably [instrumentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/examples.html#examples-instrumentation) has the needed events. The caching example has to have a way to intercept load events.

Comment: I need one Bar per sqlalchemy Session. I can catch the load with an instrumentation event, but I can't attach it in a per-session basis.

Comment: Once you look at a Session object, you can cheaply check if it has an associated Bar. If it isn't, you can associate a Bar right on the spot. If you get a Session implicitly, you can modify your code to get a Session explicitly first, and check/fix it. What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: The problem is that I have to jump through a number of hoops to make that strategy work. I have to somehow "associate" Sessions and Bars. I have to use some sort of instrumentation to detect when a new object is being constructed. All of this seems a lot of code for just wanting to pass extra parameters to the object. I was hoping someone could point out a cleaner way of doing it.